# ruby on rails - if I have 2 models can I sort them both at once?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say I have an Image model and a Video model how can I display them both in index by date

Comment: I suggest creating a third model, `Media`, which will link to either image or video. It will also handle timestamps and will be easy to paginate/sort.

Comment: Are you able to show an example, only if you can since I'm a beginner in rails. Thanks either way!

Answer (score 1):

I am going to take the torch here. :) What Sergio means is something like this:

```
class Media < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :image
  belongs_to :video
end
```

Then you can sort/filter/paginate it easily

```
@media = Media.where('created_at > ?', 2.days.ago).order(:id)
```

Just don't forget to create a corresponding media record when you add a new image/video

```
image = ...
Media.create(image: image)
```

Comment: This is good but it could be refined by making the `belongs_to` polymorphic, so instead of belonging to either an `image` or `video` you belong to a `file` which can be of any type.  Another possibility would be to use inheritance and make `Video` and `Image` both subclasses of `Media`.

Comment: @numbers1311407: good points, thanks. This is the simplest one, though, I think. As a beginner, Hipady has a lot to worry about. At this stage, making things work is more important than making things right. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with `UNION` sql function:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('
  (
  SELECT images.id, images.created_at, 'Image' as type
  FROM images
  ) UNION ALL (
  SELECT videos.id, videos.created_at, 'Video' as type
  FROM videos
  )
  ORDER BY created_at
')
```

If you need addition fields you can simply add them (but for both selects)